# Ruby command fails in Windows Ruby Command prompt with 'cannot load such file'

Tags: ruby, rubygems

I'm a C# / PowerShell guy totally struggling with some Ruby basics here.  I am [following a blog post](https://guillermo-roman.com/migrating-wordpress-blog-to-github-pages/) to convert some content from WordPress into markdown using Ruby scripts.

I have Ruby installed on Windows, running version 2.6.5 and have the `Command Prompt with Ruby` running.

I've successfully downloaded the gems mentioned here.

```
gem install jekyll-import
gem install hpricot
gem install open_uri_redirections
gem install reverse_markdown

//above worked

//below fails
ruby -rubygems -e 'require "jekyll-import";
JekyllImport::Importers::WordpressDotCom.run({
  "source" => "c:\git\wordPress\export.xml",
  "no_fetch_images" => false,
  "assets_folder" => "assets/images"
})'
```

The error looks like this:

```
C:\git\foxdeploy.io>ruby -rubygems -e 'require "jekyll-import";
Traceback (most recent call last):
        1: from C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
        C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require': 
         cannot load such file -- ubygems (LoadError)
```

I've tried saving this command as a `.rb` file, but it fails as well, with this error:

```
ruby .\import.rb
./import.rb:5: syntax error, unexpected tSTRING_BEG, expecting end-of-input
```

Comment: The option `-r` allows you to require a file from the command line. `ruby -rfoo` requires a file `foo.rb`. Hence `ruby -rubygems` requires a file `ubygems.rb

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I found the answer.  It looks like on modern ruby, you don't teld to specify `-rubygems` any longer, so I instead placed my commands in a file called `import.rb` like this:

```
//import.rb
require "jekyll-import";
puts "Processing file 1";
JekyllImport::Importers::WordpressDotCom.run({ "source" => "wordpress1.xml"})

puts "Processing file 2";
JekyllImport::Importers::WordpressDotCom.run({ "source" => "wordpress2.xml"})
```

Then ran the script like so:

`ruby .\import.rb`